# Image Views showing in different sizes - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller

I am creating some image Views programmatically inside a view(created in Storyboard) on 2 different parts of code in the same VC, but I am getting different results.
Here is my code:

```
var images: Int?

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {

 switch images {

    case 0:
        imagesCount = countImages.noImage

    case 1:
        imageView1 = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: Int((viewForImages.frame.width)), height: Int((viewForImages.frame.height))))
        imageView1.image = UIImage(data: imageData1!)

        viewForImages.addSubview(imageView1)


    case 2:
        for view in self.viewForImages.subviews {
            view.removeFromSuperview()
        }
        imageView1 = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: Int((viewForImages.frame.width) / 2) - 1, height: Int((viewForImages.frame.height))))
        imageView1.image = UIImage(data: imageData1!)
        viewForImages.addSubview(imageView1)

        imageView2 = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: Int(imageView1.frame.width) + 1, y: 0, width: Int((viewForImages.frame.width) / 2), height: Int(viewForImages.frame.height)))
        imageView2.image = UIImage(data: imageData2!)

        viewForImages.addSubview(imageView2)



    case 3:
        for view in self.viewForImages.subviews {
            view.removeFromSuperview()
        }
        imageView1 = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: Int((viewForImages.frame.width) / 2) - 1, height: Int((viewForImages.frame.height))))
        imageView1.image = UIImage(data: imageData1!)
        viewForImages.addSubview(imageView1)

        imageView2 = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: Int((viewForImages.frame.width) / 2) + 1, y: 0, width: Int((viewForImages.frame.width) / 2), height: Int((viewForImages.frame.height) / 2) - 1))
        imageView2.image = UIImage(data: imageData2!)

        viewForImages.addSubview(imageView2)

        imageView3 = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: Int((viewForImages.frame.width) / 2) + 1, y: Int(imageView2.frame.height) + 1, width: Int((viewForImages.frame.width) / 2), height: Int((viewForImages.frame.height)) / 2))
        imageView3.image = UIImage(data: imageData3!)

        viewForImages.addSubview(imageView3)

    default:
        break

    }
}
```

[image: Images appear like this]

The above code is showing the image Views properly but I am also saving these images in Core Data and when I open this view again, then in viewDidLoad(), I have added this code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
            self.imageView1 = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: Int((viewForImages.frame.width) / 2) - 1, height: Int((viewForImages.frame.height))))

            if let data = entry.imageData1 {
                self.imageView1.image = UIImage(data: data)
            }
            viewForImages.addSubview(imageView1)

            self.imageView2 = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: Int((viewForImages.frame.width) / 2) + 1, y: 0, width: Int((viewForImages.frame.width) / 2), height: Int((viewForImages.frame.height) / 2) - 1))

            if let data = entry.imageData2 {
                self.imageView2.image = UIImage(data: data)
            }
            viewForImages.addSubview(imageView2)

           self.imageView3 = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: Int((viewForImages.frame.width) / 2) + 1, y: Int(imageView2.frame.height) + 1, width: Int((viewForImages.frame.width) / 2), height: Int((viewForImages.frame.height)) / 2))
            if let data = entry.imageData3 {
                self.imageView3.image = UIImage(data: data)
            }
            viewForImages.addSubview(imageView3)
}
```

So, whenever VC loads, images appear like this below:
[image]

Note: viewForImages is the view that I created using Storyboard and entry is an entity with 3 attribute: image Data1,2,3 of type Binary Data(NSData).
Now when this view appears, If view already has images, it runs the above code, but first imageView1 covers around 80% of the view and other 2 image Views rarely appear. Why so?

Comment: What do you mean by rarely appear? Are they hidden randomly or they appear everytime but the size is small?

Comment: imageView1 covers most of the view(viewForImages). Its' width is not half like I programmed. It's much more than that. That's why the next image views appear almost at the end of view. So, only 20 % of the both the images appear(one is on the top of another like 3 images in Twitter).

Comment: @AksharPatel I have added the screenshots. You can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I got it figured out.

In `viewDiDLoad()` method, before the `switch` statement, I added the following line and it now works.

```
self.viewForImages.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change content mode

```
imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
```

Comment: Nope, it has gotten even worse.

Comment: I have added the screenshots.